# Send data as a javascript array

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

**HTML**

```
<li id="li-tip-line">
   <table>
        <tbody><tr>
           <td>
            <label for="lblTipLine" data-petkey="dog">Dog Tip Line Amount :</label></td>
             <td>
            <input type="text" name="tip-line-amount" id="tip-line-amount" value="0.00" class="cls-tip-line-amount"></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
           <td>
            <label for="lblTipLine" data-petkey="bruiser">Bruiser Tip Line Amount :</label></td>
            <td>
         <input type="text" name="tip-line-amount" class="tip-line-amount" value="0.00" class="cls-tip-line-amount"></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody></table>
 </li>
```

**UI**

[image]

**My Question**

When user clicks the 'paid' button,need to send the "data-petkey" value and the "tip-line-amount" as an array ? How can I do that ?

Comment: I think you mean javascript array, right?!

Comment: Send where? What have you tried?

Comment: **Note:** ID's must be unique.

Comment: As a sidenote, you shouldn't have two input fields with the same name and id.

Comment: @A.Wolff Yep.I use jQuery also.

Comment: @Sampath there's no such thing as a jQuery array, jQuery is a javascript library, not a language.

Comment: @Anton Ok sure I'll remove that id and will put a class.

Comment: @u_mulder send to my action method on asp.net mvc app.

Comment: Are you talking about on button click get an object with `{dog : 5.3, bruiser: 2.6}`?

Comment: @Pavlo Exactly.You're right. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use .map()

```
var arrData = $('[data-petkey],.tip-line-amount').map(function(){
      return ($(this).hasClass('tip-line-amount')?this.value:$(this).data('petkey'));
}).get();
//returns ["dog", "0.00", "bruiser", "0.00"]
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/6x3am/)

---

If you want 2 seperate arrays do this

```
var arrDataKey = $('[data-petkey]').map(function(){
      return $(this).data('petkey');
}).get();

var arrLine = $('.tip-line-amount').map(function(){
      return this.value;
}).get();
```

---

If you want a JSON object `{bruiser:"0.00",dog:"0.00"}` use .each()

```
$('button').click(function () {
    var data = {};
    $(this).closest('table').find('[data-petkey]').each(function () {
        data[$(this).data('petkey')] = $(this).closest('tr').find('.tip-line-amount').val();
    });
    console.log(data);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/6x3am/4/)

Comment: Can you tell me how to send this array into server (in my case, asp.net mvc) and extract the array content separately ?

Answer (score 0):

Anton's answer is awesome. But maybe what you really want to do is send the post request via ajax.
suppose you form like this:

```
<form method="post" action="paid.aspx" id="payform">
<li id="li-tip-line">
    <table>
        <tbody><tr>
        <td>
        <label for="lblTipLine" data-petkey="dog">Dog Tip Line Amount :</label></td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" name="tip-line-amount" id="tip-line-amount" value="0.00" class="cls-tip-line-amount"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <label for="lblTipLine" data-petkey="bruiser">Bruiser Tip Line Amount :</label></td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" name="tip-line-amount" class="tip-line-amount" value="0.00" class="cls-tip-line-amount"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</li>
</form>
```

and use this script

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#payform").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.post($("#payform").attr('action'),$("#payform").serialize())
                .done(function(data) {
                    // handle the result from the server
                    alert(data);
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```